# Generate QR code by looping through rows in specific dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a python newbie and the similar questions on stackoverflow regarding this just didn't make sense.

I have the following table below. My goal is to create a fourth column, combining the data from the first 3, to create unique URLs. For each row in the fourth column, I need to generate a new QR Code. How can I do this? I've attached my code below, but I can't seem to figure out the "loop" logic I need.

Table:

```
|EventID |EventName |URL                |
|A       |event 1   |www.qualtrics.com/1|
|B       |event 2   |www.qualtrics.com/1|
|C       |event 3   |www.qualtrics.com/1|
|D       |event 4   |www.qualtrics.com/1|
```

Code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import qrcode

#### SET WORKING DIRECTORY ####
if not os.path.exists("<some path>"):
        os.makedirs("<some path>")
        
os.chdir("<some path>")

#### READ EXCEL FILE ####
df = pd.read_excel("QR.xlsx")

#### CREATE NEW COLUMN W/ EMBEDDED DATA URL ####
df["FourthColumn"] = df["URL"].astype(str) + "?e=" + df["EventID"].astype(str) + "&en=" + df["EventName"].astype(str)
      
for column in df:
    column = df["FourthColumn"]
    
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
        box_size=10,
        border=2,
        )

    qr.make()

    img = qr.make_image()
    img.save("test.png")
```

Comment: What's the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

This  is a way how  to loop by rows  of 4 column

```
for row in  list(df["FourthColumn"]):
    
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
        box_size=10,
        border=2,
        )
    qr.add_data(row)

    qr.make(fit=True)

    img = qr.make_image()
    img.save("test.png")
```

Comment: how can I make the img.save() dynamic so it saves each one by it's name?

Answer (score 0):

You should define a function, which not only generates your `url` but also creates your `qrcode`.

We will use `urllib.parse.quote` to ensure the `url` link is valid.

```
import urllib

def url_qr(row):
    url = urllib.parse.quote(f'{row["URL"]}?e={row["EventID"]}&en={row["EventName"]}')
    qr = qrcode.make(url)
    qr.save(f'{row["EventName"]}.png')
    return url

df['Fourth'] = df.apply(url_qr, axis=1)
```

---

Output

```
  EventID  ...                                        Fourth
0       A  ...  www.qualtrics.com/1%3Fe%3DA%26en%3Devent%201
1       B  ...  www.qualtrics.com/1%3Fe%3DB%26en%3Devent%202
2       C  ...  www.qualtrics.com/1%3Fe%3DC%26en%3Devent%203
3       D  ...  www.qualtrics.com/1%3Fe%3DD%26en%3Devent%204
```

Comment: this adds unknown numbers and percentage signs (%) to the URL?

Comment: This formats the URL in the proper format. Your URL won't work as it has spaces. For example %20 is space. If you opened thag link in your browser it would work. If you don't want thag simply pass URL without urllib